# How to scan a folder recursively in ffmpeg to check for presence of subtitles?

Tags: unix, recursion, ffmpeg

I have a folder (with subfolders) of videos on my Raspberry Pi, some containing soft-embedded subtitles and some without.

I want to use ffmpeg to check for the presence of the soft-embedded subtitle, and return a result against each filename so that I can locate.

The videos may be mp4, mkv or avi.

I have been using this command successfully but in a limited way as it only works for .mp4 files and doesn't check recursively. The output is a nice list with either a 0 or 1 at the beginning of the line, where 1 means that there is no subtitle.

```
for f in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -c copy -map 0:s:0 -frames:s 1 -f null - -v 0 -hide_banner; echo $? "$f" ; done
```

I have tried all manner of ways like find and -exec, read, xargs, all to no avail. The below is the closest I've got, but it doesn't deal with whitespaces properly so filenames including spaces are split over two lines and the command seems to run only one word at a time, so it fails and shows 1 for everything.

```
for f in `find /mnt/SSD/ | grep -E '(.mp4|.mkv|.avi)'`; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -c copy -map 0:s:0 -frames:s 1 -f null - -v 0 -hide_banner; echo $? "$f" ; done
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `for` command generates the list of items to loop through from the space separated list of words. You can avoid splitting filenames by reading the output of `find` command line by line, e.g.:

```
find . -iname "*.mp4" -o -iname "*.mkv" -o -iname "*.avi" | \
while read f; do \
  subs_num=$(ffprobe -v quiet -select_streams s -show_entries stream=codec_type -of default=noprint_wrappers=1 "$f" | grep codec_type=subtitle | wc -l); \
  [ $subs_num -gt 0 ] && echo "Subtitles: $subs_num File: $f"; \
done
```

BTW, yo can use `ffprobe` to detect subtitles streams. The above command counts them and prints the results only for videos with subtitles.

Comment: This is great, just tested and works brilliantly - thank you! Small question - how could it be tweaked to show 0 if there are no subtitles?

Comment: Just remove check for zero part `[ $subs_num -gt 0 ] && `